# Where can i find and select 'Bulb mode' on my Nikon D3300

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3300, bulb-mode

Could someone please tell me where to find bulb mode on my Nikon D3300??

Comment: Have you read the user manual prior to asking these questions?

Comment: Had a look through the user manual contents page but cannot find the bulb mode or burst mode section.

Comment: for future references you can always look up PDF version of manual and search for keyword https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xq9n08r4qaogj6/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-28%20at%2010.54.50%20AM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulb is positioned on the shutter speed dial as the slowest shutter speed, way down just past the 30" second shutter speed.  It is a long way down there speaking of rotation.

Because it is inconveniently so far down, and to come back up, there is also an X speed next to it.  This X is the selected flash sync shutter speed, and on D3300, probably always shows as 1/200 second. So in some cases, for fast convenience, you may not need to come all the way back up.  (but selected shutter speed applies only to M and S modes)

Answer (score 2):

Set to Manual mode (M), rotate command dial to the left (pp. 68 and 71 of User's Manual).